# Ubuntu 13.10 no top right bar buttons (power, network, calender)

Tags: indicator, desktop-environments

The top right corner of the screen which previously housed the power, network, calender indicators are nowhere to be seen now. I had an upgrade yesterday from 13.04 and cannot find them anywhere. I have also installed Ubuntu Tweak. But cannot find indicator option anywhere.
I am pretty new to Ubuntu.

Some help please.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem to this not long ago and fixed it with this command:

```
sudo restart lightdm
```

You'll be logged out and once you log back in if lightdm was the problem, your applets should be there again.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tried.. But didnt work.. same problem persists.. Plee help..

Comment: This problem is in Ubuntu 13.10..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd really love to help but that's the only possible solution I know at the minute. There is probably a duplicated around here that is already answered, but I'm afraid I don't have any more knowledge on the subject.

Comment: I can't edit that post (must change at least six characters) but it should be `sudo restart lightdm`.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing... I've edited it now, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

After issuing `sudo restart lightdm`, you could be stuck in a login loop.

To fix this Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and login with your user; then type:

`ls -lah | grep .Xauthority`

Make sure that the `user:group` permissions are changed from `root:root` to `username:username`. Log out and re-login.